# Proving that a $2\times 2$ matrix set is closed under addition

Tags: matrices, group-theory, proof-writing

I have the following matrix $C$ whose elements $a$ and $b$ are real.

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
 -b&a 
\end{bmatrix}$

I am supposed to show that the set of such matrices is closed under addition. I am not really sure how I am supposed to do this. Could somebody give me a hint ?

Comment: What is a closed matrix?

Comment: I suppose he meant, that matrix space generated by $a, b$ is closed under addition. By the way that space is another representation of complex numbers :) So it's also closed under multiplication too.

Comment: The hint is: suppose that you have two matrices with this form. When you add them, does the result have the same form too

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
 -b&a 
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
c & d\\ 
 -d&c 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a+c & b+d\\ 
 -(b+d)&a+c 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Can't you re use the matric C by adding it to itself ? Does it ma?ke a difference?

Comment: Yep, as simple as that. You can also extend your answer by proving that the space is closed under multiplication too, even though OP didn't ask that.

Comment: Sorry Kaster are you responding to me or to Jonas ?

Comment: He was talking to me. Anyways, he already interpreted clearly the question in the comment above. I have nothing to add.

Comment: I have a last question about closure. I assume that the elements also must be the same ? As in the first element of the second line must be negative for it to be closed, right ? Sorry it's m first time that I see this.

Comment: No, $a$ and $b$ can be any real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that if you have two matrices with that structure and you add them, you get another matrix with the same structure. This is, let a,b,c and d be real numbers and consider the following matrices:
$$ A=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & a \end{array} \right) 
$$ and  $$ B= 
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
c & d \\
-d & c \end{array} \right) $$
then
$$
A+B=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a+c & b+d \\
-(b+d) & a+c \end{array} \right) $$

which has the same structure as the two matrices that you're adding together. These matrices are really useful to represent complex numbers, where A represents the complex number a+bi and B represents the complex number c+di. They're useful because the product of these numbers is
$$(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd) +(ad+bc)i$$
which is represented by the matrix
$$ P=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
ac-bd & ad+bc \\
-(ad+bc) & ac-bd \end{array} \right) 
$$
and you can check that $P=AB$, the product of both matrices.

Comment: Yeah this is what I understood also. By the way can't you re use the matrix C by adding it to itself ?

Comment: you want it to be as general as possible. That is the reason that you use two matrices that are not necessarily the same one.

Comment: Ok last question, if I want to prove that this matrix is closed under multiplication by a scalar or by another matrix, must the elements keep the same form ? As in must the first element of the second line be negative or it can be prositive also ?

Comment: @copper we want to show that if we add *any* two elements of $C$ (that is, not necessarily adding an element to itself), we get some other element of $C$.

Comment: Ok yeah, I understand that now, thanks

Comment: to be closed under something it means that the matrix keeps the same structure, just as you say. I think i proved it was closed under mutiplication by another matrix on my answer and the multiplication by scalar is really similar. I hope you found it useful :)

Comment: Ok sorry, when I say that it keeps the same structure I mean it keeps its 2 x 2 form, regardless of the elements in it. So it can have a positive element as the first element of the second line, right ?